# What is difference between history.push("/") and <Redirect to ="/" />

Tags: reactjs

```
<li className="nav-item">
          <span
            className="nav-link text-warning"
            onClick={() => {
              signout(() => {
                return < Redirect to="/" />;
              });
            }}
          >
            Signout
          </span>
</li>
```

So if the user is authenticated I will show him signout button and After clicking signout button, I should be able to move to home "/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect will **replace** the current route with the desired one. On the other hand push will add the route to the history stack.
Redirect is equivalent to history.replace

Comment: Ok. So in this code, can I use history,push("/"). Please tell me where to use Redirect and history?

Comment: after a signout you might actually want to use redirect.
the <Redirect /> component is just a convenient wrapper around history.redirect - you can use them interchangeably.
Whenever you don't want the use to be able to go back to the same route you should use redirect. otherwise you should use push